# New menu item called "arch_grub" emerged as a temporary boot device

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub

I have Ubuntu installed along with Arch. I re-installed Arch a few times already. Now it works well. Once when I was re-installing Arch during boot when I chose the "Choose temporary boot devise" option at BIOS and I saw a new menu item (among "Hdd", "Usb", "Dvd") appeared being `arch_grub`. I ran boot-repair utility later but this menu item is still there.

How do I get rid of it?

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for alex: 

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a1bc4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1          526336   382824447   191149056   83  Linux
/dev/sda2            2048      526335      262144    b  W95 FAT32
/dev/sda3       382826494  1953523711   785348609    5  Extended
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5      1946028032  1953523711     3747840   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6   *   382834688  1946025983   781595648   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

and

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 182.3G  0 part /media/alex/arch
├─sda2   8:2    0   256M  0 part /media/alex/arch_boot
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   3.6G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda6   8:6    0 745.4G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```